# Select DataTable row, filtered by GUID

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, filter, guid

I have a non-primary-key column with GUID's (with DataType System.Guid) and [it appears](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/3a855416-cc6c-4dbd-99cd-3784fa89d460) you cant use DataTable.Select on that column. (Only DataRowCollection.Find but it requires GUID to be Primary Key column, which is not my case)

Anyway, I need to get that row `WHERE UniqueId = *GUID*`

Maybe there are some LINQ tricks that can do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

C#:

```
var filteredRows = from dtr in yourDataTable.Rows
                   where ((System.Guid)dtr["MyGuidColumn"]) == myFilterGuid
                   select dtr;
```

VB:

```
Dim filteredRows = From dtr In yourDataTable.Rows _
                   Where DirectCast(dtr("MyGuidColumn"), System.Guid) = myFilterGuid _
                   Select dtr
```